# How to handle limitation of in-memory entities to Unit Test class/service which is using EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I going to unit test a service which is using Entity Framework 6.

Sample scenario, it would have Blog and Post entity, Blog having zero or more Posts. In the service method it would return list of entities which having Blog's Title and Title of first Post of that Blog. It looks like below.

```
public class BlogService 
{
    private IBloggingContext _context;

    public BlogService(IBloggingContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<BlogPostSumarry> GeBlogSummary()
    {
        var query = from b in _context.Blogs
                    orderby b.Name
                    select new BlogPostSumarry
                    {
                        BlogTitle = b.Name,
                        PostTitle = b.Posts.FirstOrDefault().Title
                    };

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

}

Unit Test Method

```
[Test]
    public void GeBlogSummary_WhenMatchFound()
    {
        var post = new List<Post>()
        {
            new Post() {PostId=45, Title="abc"}
        };

        var data = new List<Blog>
        {
            new Blog { Name = "BBB" },
            new Blog { Name = "ZZZ" },
            new Blog { Name = "AAA" },
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new BlogService(mockContext.Object);
        var blogs = service.GeBlogSummary();

        Assert.AreEqual(3, blogs.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("AAA", blogs[0].BlogTitle);
        Assert.AreEqual("BBB", blogs[1].BlogTitle);
        Assert.AreEqual("ZZZ", blogs[2].BlogTitle);
    }
```

Unit test I use to mock DbContext and DbSet use in memory data. Problem is in case of blogs doesn’t have any post unit test will giving null reference exception where as in real scenario (Database) it works fine. This is because in a case of in memory it is Linq to Object where as in EF it is Linq to Entity.

For a example if I change the method like below it works UnitTest

```
public List<BlogPostSumarry> GeBlogSummary()
    {
        var query = from b in _context.Blogs
                    orderby b.Name
                    select new BlogPostSumarry
                    {
                        BlogTitle = b.Name,
//Manually checks for null validation works but any approach without change code for sack of unit test
                        PostTitle = b.Posts.Any() ? b.Posts.FirstOrDefault().Title : null
                    };

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Once approach is change linq query for null check but I think it is not good approach. If so any suggestion how can I achieve my test?

Comment: None of your blogs have posts so how do you expect `b.Posts.FirstOrDefault()` to return anything?

Comment: It is just a one scenario. it depend of relationship between Blog and Posts. In here I thought like Blogs can have  none more more Posts. Here is None scenario.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. If you use `FirstOrDefault` then you have to be prepared for having to deal with `null`. Instead do something like `PostTitle 
 = b.Posts.FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? "No posts found"`

Comment: @FCin A "little" detail here is that `?.` operator is not supported in expression trees (yet), so your suggestion simply doesn't compile.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, I didn't try it out, but the idea is to just handle `null` if there are no posts.

Comment: @FCin I know, but the point is that in LINQ to Entities query you *don't have to*, since `null`s are handled naturally in SQL. I personally disagree with writing a redundant code just to make it testable.

Comment: @IvanStoev It is not about being testable, but about using right methods for right things. It is completely reasonable for `Blog` to not have any `Posts`. Using `b.Posts.FirstOrDefault().Title` is wrong, because there may be situation in real world when someone creates new blog which doesn't have posts, so returning `Title` is not possible. Either use `b.Posts.First().Title` or handle `Blog` with no `Posts`.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you don't do isolated unit tests for database layer. You do integration tests for this code. You set up a real database (can be LocalDB, it is easy to configure) and run your tests against this test database.

When you try to mock your database, you are testing a mock of your database layer, not the real thing. And you might spend a lot of time tinkering with the mock, but will never get to behave exacty like the database will behave (unless you plan to write a copy of your database).

One of the reason for differerences - LINQ for memory objects just works differently to when it is translated to SQL. You can easily write LINQ that will be perfectly testable with mocks and you'll hvae passable tests. But when executed on real DB the same LINQ will fail because LINQ provider would not know how to translate that to SQL.

Whatever you do with your mock, your memory object will not be the same as SQL requests fired to your DB.  And SQL requests is what you are really testing. If you are not testing these, then there is no point in pretending there is a DB behind the storage. Might as well just skip these tests.

Comment: You can write easily mockable ef code that tests queries which is what you usually want. This doesn't answer the question and is just an opinion...

Comment: @FCin Yes you can. Though amount of time you spend on a mock will exceed the time to set up testing DB. And it'll still won't be the 100% identical behaviour to the DB.

Comment: That is completely dependent on project you work on. I have hundreds of ef unit tests in my project and not a single one exceeds 10 lines of code. I have 1 method for generating context mock and that is it. On the other hand there are things that are very difficult to mock, but it doesn't mean that you should never write unit tests for ef.

Comment: Integration tests are good, but quite expensive; also, they don't say the sample units behave correctly. So obviously, next to integration tests (especially regression) unit tests are also necessary. Obviously you don't test the DAL because of the lack of testable functions, but you will want to test the BL which uses the DAL to query the database - and since EF IS your DAL, you'll want to mock EF functionality (most prominently DbSets and exposed IQueryables). So while your point may be valid, there is more to it.

Comment: Integration test to a database are the only way to test ef effectively since linq queries to in memory objects is completely different than linq queries to a true sql data source.  I've seen many senior devs get tripped up by this because they've written unit tests that pass because of an in memory provider and then fail when handed over to testers because the same linq statement can't be translated to sql.  Let's not even get started with testing at scale instead of with a completely clean database.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro in what sense integration tests are expensive? yes, they are taking longer to run, but that's why you have CI server. You need to think a bit to write tests, but with any kind of test you need to think. And you talk about "lack of testable functions" - what do you mean?

Comment: @Fran Thank you! Something I have not managed to explain in my answer

Comment: @trailmax integration tests execute your production code and need all resources your original code would require. For example, settings, databases and of course binaries of all assemblies. Additionally, for integration tests to be effective you'll have to ensemble all parameters that will help you identify error cases you wouldn't find in every execution for manual testing, which makes them incredibly hard to maintain in the way so they keep being effective. And your DAL simply implements your connection to the data sources - there aren't many functions and of course few serious error sources.